# Method does not presize the allocation of a collection

Tags: java, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

Sonar shows that me this bug `Performance - Method does not presize the allocation of a collection`

> Method mapping(ResponseEntity) does not presize the allocation of a
>   collection

Here is the code:

```
private Set<ResponseDTO> mapping(ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity) {
    final Set<ResponseDTO> result = new HashSet<>();
    final JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(responseEntity.getBody());
    final JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.optJSONArray("issues");
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
        final JSONObject innerObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
        final String name = innerObject.optString("key");
        result.add(new ResponseDTO().name(name));
    }
    return result;
}
```

Why does Sonar flag this as an error and how can I fix it ?

Comment: Read the message carefully. What does it mean? Which collection are you using in this method? Is there any way you could know its size in advance?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, you're operating on an array of known length and add all elements to the set. Assuming you don't have any duplicates the resulting set should contain the same number of elements.

However, you're creating a set with a default initial capacity, i.e. `new HashSet<>()`. That might cause the need for the set to be resized which isn't a problem in itself but would be unnecessary and thus *could* cause some performance hit.

To get rid of that, create the set via `new HashSet<>(jsonArray.length())` right before iterating.

Answer (score 0):

Just to bypass the error, we could do the below:

```
private Set<ResponseDTO> mapping(ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity) {
final JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(responseEntity.getBody());
final JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.optJSONArray("issues");

int initialCapacity = (int) Math.ceil(jsonArray.length() / 0.75);
final Set<ResponseDTO> result = new HashSet<>(initialCapacity);

for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
    final JSONObject innerObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
    final String name = innerObject.optString("key");
    result.add(new ResponseDTO().name(name));
}
return result; }
```

Since HashSet's default load factor is 0.75, if we know the expected size, we can calculate the initial capacity as expectedSize / 0.75. However, HashSet's internal mechanics will ensure the capacity is a power of two. So, if you're trying to optimize for both space and time, the capacity should be the smallest power of two greater than expectedSize / 0.75.

This adjustment should address the SonarQube warning regarding collection allocation.